# The destructor for the class member `B`, why is it invoked in the snippet below?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++14, delete-operator

From §5.3.5[expr.delete]/1, I can understand that the destructor for the object `*a` is **not** invoked in the snippet below. But I didn't understand why is the destructor for the class member `B` invoked in this case, as can be seen in this [live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d1bf3f2a54acea32).

```
#include <iostream>
class A
{
public:
   class B{ public: ~B(){ std::cout << "B dtor" << '\n'; } };
   A() { p = new B(); }
   operator B*() { return p; }
private:
   B* p;
};

int main()
{
   A* a = new A();
   delete *a;
   std::cout << "end" << '\n';
}
```

Would appreciate some quote from the Standard explaining this.

Comment: I didn't know there was a `language-lawyer` tag. Awesome!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your `delete *a` applies operator `delete` to a *non-pointer* expression `*a` of type `A`. The only way this can be legal is when type `A` is implicitly convertible to some pointer type.

> **5.3.5 Delete [expr.delete]**
>
> **1** ... The operand shall have a pointer to object type, or a class type having a single non-explicit conversion
>   function (12.3.2) to a pointer to object type.
>
> **2** If the operand has a
>   class type, the operand is converted to a pointer type by calling the
>   above-mentioned conversion function, and the converted operand is used
>   in place of the original operand for the remainder of this section.

In this case your class `A` is implicitly convertible to `B *`, which is exactly what happens when you do `delete *a`.

In other words, your `delete *a` is actually interpreted as

```
delete (*a).operator B*();
```

It is `B` you `delete` in your code, not `A`. This is why the destructor of `B` is called.

If you wanted to destroy the `A` object, you'd have to do

```
delete a;
```

(note, no `*`). That would not call `B`'s destructor.

Comment: It seems so obvious, after reading the answer. Thanks anyway.

Comment: What would be the benefit of this construction?

Comment: @Wake up Brazil: It might be useful, say, when you implement some sort of "smart pointer" class. If object `A a;` itself represents a generalized "pointer", then you might want to be able to do `delete a;` This is when this implicit conversion comes into play. There are quite a few pitfalls in such approach to deletion, but for what it is worth...

Answer (score 0):

if you tried to implement smart pointer - then you probably should examine [boost sources](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/boost/move/unique_ptr.hpp)

in a nutshell smart pointer pattern provide the idea of some small object, that wrap original object and destroy it as it's not required.

for example very simple example, also without custom deleters and so on:

```
<template class T>
class scope_delete
{
 public:
   scope_delete(T* ptr) : p(ptr) {}
   ~scope_delete() { delete p; }
   T* operator->() { return p; }
 private:
   T * p;
};

// somewere in programm
{
  auto obj = scope_delete(new MyCLasss);
  obj->some_fun();
} // here stack object obj will be deleted and remove original object.
```

for detailed information you should read some books, or I've just google this [article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15351/Implementing-a-simple-smart-pointer-in-c).